# WPF showing whitespace that is not present in designer view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm playing around with WPF in Visual Studio code, attempting to create a GUI.

The GUI looks fine in my design view, but when I compile / run the application, it shows some whitespace that is not present in the design view. The XAML code is below.

```
<Window x:Class="GUIProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUIProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="1200"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid Background="#FF34495E">
        <Rectangle x:Name="SidebarWrapper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="583" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Fill="#FF2C3E50" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="650" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Fill="#FFE74C3C"/>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1195" Fill="#FF2C3E50" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To give you an idea of what it looks like in the design view:
[image: Design view]

To give you an idea of what it looks like when i run it:
[image: When running]

When I set the `SidebarWrapper` height to 600 (window height - topbar (650 - 50)), it removes the whitespace and gives me the result that I want. But the design view in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxNfx.png) image shows that it partially goes out of the main window, which I do not think is correct.
[image: this]

I'm pretty sure that I'm either missing something, or did something wrong. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

---

Edited code that utilizes the grid.

```
<Window x:Class="GUIProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUIProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="1200"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True">

    <Grid Background="#FF34495E" Height="650">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="600"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1000"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle x:Name="SidemenuWrapper" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FF2C3E50"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="TopmenuWrapper" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Fill="#2c3e50"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If you use the grid it's already embedded in and assign `grid.row` `grid.column` definitions to its children you would both fix your issue and make a more fluid layout instead of relying on margins.

Comment: I googled a bit and attempted to change my code. I've added the edited code to my question. Is this the correct way to implement it? Also another small question: logically it's telling me that it can't define a second rectangle with the same name, where can I delete the old definition?

Comment: @jd1 what it means by `not the same name` is about `x:Name="toto"`, in your .XAML file you may not have 2 elements with same name. Finally, as you use RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions, you may remove all `Height=` from your rectangles, these are the RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions that set your dimensions.

Comment: @Siegfried.V I saw that I was able to remove the height statements. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah sorry looked away, did you get a full remedy or did you need an example? The only place you would set your height (unless there's a specific reason in this scenario) is on the first row if you really need it to be a specific height. The second row should stretch the full height right? However it looks like you got the hang of the row/column/spans which is super handy to know.

Comment: @ChrisW. I've got it working. I didn't realize a grid system like this existed. It's very simple and resolved all the issues I was having. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So like we talked about the [Grid Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid?view=winrt-20348) is super handy when creating layouts in xaml, it's like `table` element in `HTML`. While relying on adhoc static margins, padding, etc is generally not the best route. So something like below (omitting some default values etc for cleaner code) is more along the lines of what you're aiming for. Cheers!

```
<Grid Background="#FF34495E">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Rectangle x:Name="TopmenuWrapper" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FF2C3E50"/>
      <Rectangle x:Name="SidebarWrapper" Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FF2C3E50"/>
      <Border x:Name="ContentAreaWrapper" Grid.Row=1" Grid.Column="1"><!-- Content Here --></Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I'd say in your second `ColumnDefinition` you may set `Width="*"`, because if automatic, TopmenuWrapper and ContentAreaWrapper will not use all the avaible width, the column will take only necessary width.

Comment: @Siegfried.V You're right, editing accordingly, haven't worked in xaml in awhile and don't even have an IDE for it anymore. Couldn't even find a good download for kxaml IDE so just freehanded it :D